# Using filter to return dates

Tags: reactjs, typescript, date-formatting

I'm trying to get a new array using filter and subdays  from "date-fns" to get dates before 1, 7 and 30 days, but I'dont know exactly whats is wrong with this logic, someone could help me ?

```
const handleLoadByDate = useCallback(
    (option: number) => {
      const filtering = favorites?.filter((date: FormattedFavorites) => {
        if (option === 1) {
          return (
            new Date(date.created_at).getTime() >=
            subDays(new Date(date.created_at), 1).getTime()
          );
        }
        if (option === 7) {
          return (
            new Date(date.created_at).getTime() >=
            subDays(new Date(date.created_at), 7).getTime()
          );
        }
        return (
          new Date(date.created_at).getTime() >=
          subDays(new Date(date.created_at), 30).getTime()
        );
      });
      return filtering;
    },
    [favorites],
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number is always greater than that number minus 1. So, when you subtract days from the date, you are just making the condition always return true.

You need a different value to make that an actual comparison. From what you have written, I can't tell for sure what it should be. Perhaps just `subDays(new Date(),x).getTime()` if you want it to be within x days from now?